# Battery At 0% But Only When Charging

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, battery, lts

I am having a strange issue with my laptop. I just installed Lubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire Timeline 3810tz a few hours ago. I have noticed that my battery percentage stays at 0% only when it is charging. When I unplug the charger, it displays the correct percentage. Is there a way to fix this?